# SQL Server 2008r2 Commit performance issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, cursor, commit

I have large SP that contains a primary outer cursor (I know, I know, but I had to examine each row to determine what to do with it, e.g. write to child tables, exception table, reports, etc) and some inner cursors.  Within these cursors are calls to other SPs that do the actual INSERTS/UPDATE and DELETES.

At the top of the outer most cursor I do a BEGIN TRAN and at the end of the cursor, before I loop back up to the TOP, I do a COMMIT TRAN.  Committing all the work (parent and children) for the outer most's row.

This is a standalone process that runs with no users accessing the target DB as it happens during a software upgrade.

I have a debug statement that displays the milliseconds duration to process the outer cursor.  At most of our clients where I run this, that duration is pretty consistent through out the whole process however at one client that duration get progressively slower.  Additionally, it appears that the last COMMIT at this client site takes 84 seconds to process whereas other it does not impact the duration any, same average time.

The code it identical between the clients.  The Isolation Level is identical.

The sp_configure options are nearly identical.

Client DBMS's is on a virtual server with good to average SQLIO times to the data and log.  Testing a select */into [table] from a million row table only took 3 seconds, so writes and auto-committing seems ok.

Thoughts or ideas to diagnose further?

Comment: There could a million reasons for this. Without seeing some code and a lot more detail nobody can offer more than speculation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a poor performing index used by one of the called sp's - it was doing a tablespace scan, which was gettting progressively slower as the seeks times increased.